# getline reading a file with a single entry after deleting a second entry weird behaviour

Tags: c

I am using getline to read a file. It works perfectly except for one weird behaviour which I cannot figure out why. Consider the following piece of code. Now test.txt is a file containing a single entry say 1. I use the following code and I get the desired result i.e getline reads the entry 1. Now I add another entry say 2 now the file test.txt contains entries 1 and 2, getline reads the both the entries as expected. However now I when I delete the second entry 2 from test.txt and run the code again getline reads an extra line. I am not sure why. Now if I delete the old file test.txt and create a new file test.txt with only one entry 1 the following code works perfectly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *line = malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    size_t len = 100;
    ssize_t read;
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        printf("Retrieved line of length %zu :\n", read);
        printf("%s", line);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because there is a newline character left...

Comment: How can one avoid this without creating a new file again

Comment: Delete it with backspace?

Comment: Which editor are you using to modify test.txt?

Comment: I have 100 files like this. I can't ensure that by deleting with backspace. Is there any other solution

Comment: Your code nicely reports `"Retrieved line of length %zu :\n"`, so be kind and post in your question the values you saw and the values you expected.  IOWs, rather the describe your  output - _post_ your output and describe your expectations.

Comment: "I can't ensure that by deleting with backspace" --> then write a program that tests and insures the files end in one `'\n'` and change ones that don't.

Comment: Learn about your input file's *real* content by inspecting it using a hex-dump.

Answer (score 0):

Getline reads everything until the end of line character is seen. You must assure you haven't left the endline character in the deleted line. You can achieve that by pressing backspace.